# how to make current controller as default controller in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Here is code of appcontroller

```
class AppController extends Controller {

 public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'employees',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'employees',
            'action' => 'logout',
            'index'
        )
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index','add');
}
```

***ERROR***

usercontroller not found //why it is coming

my model class name is Employee
Controller name id employeesController

please help me on this as i am new to cake php

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Auth` to your used components suggests you are logging users in. You can read more about how it works [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

You can take out the Auth out and try again, or set up the user authentication.

How does your `EmployeesController` look like?

Comment: the link I posted gives details about to set up user authentication. Do you really need people to be able to log in?

Comment: how to add user authentication in app controller? 
My controller name is employeesController and the code is..
class employeesController extends AppController
{
 public function login(){
 if($this->request->is('post')){
  $t=$this->Employee->find('count',array('conditions' => array('Employee.USERNAME' => $this->request->data['Employee']['USERNAME'] ,'Employee.PASSWORD' => $this->request->data['Employee']['PASSWORD'])));
  if($t > 0){
   if($this->request->request->data['Employee']['USERNAME']=='admin')
{//admin page}
else
{//another page}

   }else{//error message}}}
}

Comment: Do not dump piles of code in the comments @vineet it's highly unreadable! In case there is any additional code useful for the question, then it should go _in the question itself_!

Comment: class employeesController extends AppController { public function login(){ if($this->request->is('post')){ $t=$this->Employee->find('count',array('conditions' => array('Employee.USERNAME' => $this->request->data['Employee']['USERNAME'] ,'Employee.PASSWORD' => $this->request->data['Employee']['PASSWORD']))); if($t > 0){ if($this->request->request->data['Employee']['USERNAME']=='admin') {admin page} else {employee page} }else{}}} }

Comment: You did not answer my question. Do you need authentication? Did you try to do it like in the tutorial? Do you need EmployeedController to be accessible only when logged in?

Comment: only some action should be accessed by admin and some by other?

Comment: That still does not answer the questions I asked. If you need authentication, try to set it up like in the tutorial